# Reading from JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json

The variable data has the following JSON

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Stade Leopold Sedar Senghor, Route de Yoff, Dakar, Senegal" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Unnamed Road, Dakar, Senegal" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "13.0 km",
                  "value" : 13007
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "23 mins",
                  "value" : 1383
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I then run the following code:

```
parsed =  json.loads(data)
```

I want to store distance "text" and "value", and duration "text" and "value" and "status" into variables in python. I tried the following code but it did not work:

```
dist = int(parsed['rows']['elements']['distance']['value'])
```

But I am getting an error

Comment: `[]` are `list`s, `{}` are `dict`s.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @shruti1810, probably a `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Answer (score 3):

The keys *rows* and *elements* are lists, so you'll need to specify an index:

```
dist = int(parsed['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have working code.
I have just changed a bit  and it works fine.
The access to dictionary it a little bit confusing. I will try to explain.
The json.dumps serialize a str to a json obj. Here for more information.
[json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps)

```
 data ={
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Stade Leopold Sedar Senghor, Route de Yoff, Dakar, Senegal" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Unnamed Road, Dakar, Senegal" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "13.0 km",
                  "value" : 13007
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "23 mins",
                  "value" : 1383
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}


data_string = json.dumps(data)
parsed =  json.loads(data_string)

print parsed['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
```

When you have a list into a dictionary first of all you have to refer the index(an integer) that you want to access and then the dictionary index with the name('string'). As you can see in the last line of the code.